# Tic-Tac-Toe in JavaScript with minimax algorithm

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to implement a Tic-Tac-Toe game using a minimax algorithm for n number of grid size in Javascript.

I have copied the algorithm from **geeksforgeeks** exactly, but in Javascript the result is not expected and something weird is happening beyond my understanding.

I'm calling the function `computerTurn(moves)` to make the computer move, and inside it calling the function `getBestMove(gridArr, depth, isMax, moves)` to get the best move via the minimax algorithm.

In both functions, I'm first checking the empty cell in the grid then assigning it with a specific turn, and then calling the getBestMove function with the new grid. However sometimes the assignment of the grid does not take place and the `getBestMove` method is called.

Secondly, when I'm printing the grid array in the `getBestMove` method, it's always printing the same array with only two elements like...

> gridArr:- 0:-[1,2,0], 1:-[0,0,0], 2:-[0,0,0]

... and every time the next empty cell is returned as `bestMove`.

At first, I thought that the same array has been passed to every `getBestMove` function but when I log the score I'm getting results from the `evaluateScore(grid)` method (which returns 10 for win, -10 to lose and 0 for draw) returning 10 and -10 as well.

See code below.

In any case, what needs to happen is in each iteration of both functions, when an empty cell is detected the function makes a move i.e assignment of turn into the grid and then pass that grid into the function call.

I'm using **1** for **'X'**, **2** for **'0'** and **0** for **empty** cells in the grid. `GRID_LENGTH` is the size of row of Tic-Tac-Toe which is 3 for now, and grid is the 2d array for storing X and 0. In the `evaluateScore` function, `WIN_LENGTH` is the length to decide winning state, which 3 in this case

[This is git repository, which creates the error(s) in question](https://github.com/mayankjaiswal00/tic-tac-toe/)

Thank You all!!

```js
function computerTurn(moves) {
  let bestValue = -1000,
    bestMove = [];

  for (let row = 0; row < GRID_LENGTH; row++) {
    for (let col = 0; col < GRID_LENGTH; col++) {
      if (grid[row][col] == 0) {
        // searching for empty cell

        grid[row][col] = 2; // making move
        moves++; // increment moves count

        let moveValue = getBestMove(grid, 0, false, moves); // checking is this is the best move

        moves--;
        grid[row][col] = 0;

        if (moveValue > bestValue) {
          // updating values
          bestMove[0] = row;
          bestMove[1] = col;
          bestValue = moveValue;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  grid[bestMove[0]][bestMove[1]] = 2;
  turn = 'X';
  return bestMove;
}

function getBestMove(gridArr, depth, isMax, moves) {
  let score = evaluateScore(gridArr);
  let arr = gridArr;

  if (score == 10 || score == -10) {
    return score;
  }

  if (moves == totalMoves) {
    return 0;
  }

  if (isMax) {
    let best = -1000;
    for (let i = 0; i < GRID_LENGTH; i++) {
      for (let j = 0; j < GRID_LENGTH; j++) {
        if (arr[i][j] == 0) {
          arr[i][j] = 2;
          moves++;
          best = Math.max(best, getBestMove(arr, depth + 1, !isMax, moves));
          arr[i][j] = 0;
          moves--;
        }
      }
    }
    return best;
  } else {
    let best = 1000;
    for (let i = 0; i < GRID_LENGTH; i++) {
      for (let j = 0; j < GRID_LENGTH; j++) {
        if (arr[i][j] == 0) {
          arr[i][j] = 1;
          moves++;
          best = Math.min(best, getBestMove(arr, depth + 1, !isMax, moves));
          arr[i][j] = 0;
          moves--;
        }
      }
    }
    return best;
  }
}

function evaluateScore(gridArr) {

  let diff = GRID_LENGTH - WIN_LENGTH;
  let len = WIN_LENGTH - 1;

  for (let i = 0; i < GRID_LENGTH; i++) { // check win for different rows

    if (diff == 0) {
      let win = true;
      for (let j = 0; j < len; j++) {

        if (gridArr[i][j] != gridArr[i][j + 1]) {
          win = false;
          break;
        }
      }
      if (win) {
        if (gridArr[i][0] == 1) {
          return -10;
        } else if (gridArr[i][0] == 2) {
          return 10;
        }
      }

    } else {

      for (let j = 0; j <= diff; j++) {
        let count = 0;
        for (let k = j; k < len; k++) {
          if ((gridArr[i][k] != gridArr[i][k + 1])) {
            count++;
          }
          if (count == len) {
            if (gridArr[i][k] == 1) {
              return -10;
            } else if (gridArr[i][k] == 2) {
              return 10;
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }

  }

  for (let i = 0; i < GRID_LENGTH; i++) { // check win for different cols

    if (diff == 0) {
      let win = true;
      for (let j = 0; j < len; j++) {

        if (gridArr[j][i] != gridArr[j][i + 1]) {
          win = false;
          break;
        }
      }
      if (win) {
        if (gridArr[0][i] == 1) {
          return -10;
        } else if (gridArr[0][i] == 2) {
          return 10;
        }
      }

    } else {

      for (let j = 0; j <= diff; j++) {
        let count = 0;
        for (let k = j; k < len; k++) {
          if ((gridArr[k][i] != gridArr[k][i + 1])) {
            count++;
          }
          if (count == len) {
            if (gridArr[k][i] == 1) {
              return -10;
            } else if (gridArr[k][i] == 2) {
              return 10;
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }

  }

  let diagonalLength = GRID_LENGTH - WIN_LENGTH;
  for (let i = 0; i <= diagonalLength; i++) { // diagonals from left to right
    for (let j = 0; j <= diagonalLength; j++) {

      let row = i,
        col = j;
      let win = true;
      for (let k = 0; k < len; k++) {
        if (gridArr[row][col] != gridArr[row + 1][col + 1]) {
          win = false;
          break;
        }
        row++;
        col++;
      }
      if (win) {
        if (gridArr[i][j] == 1) {
          return -10;
        } else if (gridArr[i][j] == 2) {
          return 10;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  let compLen = GRID_LENGTH - diagonalLength - 1;
  for (let i = 0; i >= diagonalLength; i--) { // diagonals from right to left
    for (let j = GRID_LENGTH - 1; j >= compLen; j--) {

      let row = i,
        col = j;

      let win = true;
      for (let k = 0; k < len; k++) {
        if (gridArr[row][col] != gridArr[row + 1][col - 1]) {
          win = false;
          break;
        }
        row++;
        col--;
      }
      if (win) {
        if (gridArr[i][j] == 1) {
          return -10;
        } else if (gridArr[i][j] == 2) {
          return 10;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I have made a snippet of your code.   Please update it to provide a working example.  For instance, what is `GRID_LENGTH` ?, what is `grid` etc.  There is no `evaluateScore(gridArr)` function  in your code

Comment: hey mark, i did it. Please review and try to help me

Comment: @Mayank Please click [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55431388/edit) then scroll down and click "edit snippet" and make it run in a [mcve]

Comment: @mplungjan I added the git link. All code is there please download it recreate the same issue. You will find out it in console

Comment: No way. Too much work